# Django ordering search results from get_queryset(self)

Tags: python, html, django

I am using django 2.2.10. I have a searchbar which returns search results to the showpage, using get_queryset(self) in searchresultsview(listview) class. I have set paginate_by=10. In the front-end I made links to order the table: `

`<th>Title original  <a href="?order_by=title_original&direction=asc" class="arrow up"></a> <a href="?order_by=title_original&direction=desc" class="arrow down"></a></th>`

At the start of the get_queryset(self) function I have the following code:

```
        order_by = self.request.GET.get('order_by')
        direction = self.request.GET.get('direction')
        if order_by is not None and order_by != "" and direction is not None and direction != "":
            ordering = Lower(order_by)
            if direction == 'desc':
                ordering = '-{}'.format(ordering)
            publications = Publication.objects.filter(is_deleted=False).order_by(ordering)
            '''
            paginator = Paginator(publications, 10)
            page = self.request.GET.get('page')
            try:
                all_publications = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                all_publications = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                all_publications = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
            '''

            return publications
```

The main problem is that the publications variable contain all publications, I want to restrict it to the publications from the previous get_queryset(self) call. Also the showpage is paginated (paginate_by = 10 in template).The ordering for descending does not work I get: invalid order_by arguments: ['-Lower(F(title_original))'] . If I order ascending it logically does not keep my search results.
I tried finding a stackoverflow solution but the explanation is minimal. Any help would be appreciated.

It might be easier to use django-tables, if so I am open for suggestions.

view codes:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    '''
    ListView of the initial search page.
    The function get_queryset works for the search bar and the search form home page.
    The search bar typically uses q for query otherwise a id for list search.
    Use a countries_dict to convert for example Netherlands to NL so that search succeeds.
    If a normal field is searched use __icontains if a list element is searched use: __in.
    '''
    model = Publication
    template_name = 'publications/show.html'
    context_object_name = 'publications'
    publications = Publication.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)
    #paginator = Paginator(publications, 10)
    #paginator = Paginator(publications, 25)
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_ordering(self):
        order_by = self.request.GET.get('order_by')
        direction = self.request.GET.get('direction')
        if order_by is not None and order_by != "" and direction is not None and direction != "":
            ordering = Lower(order_by)
            if direction == 'desc':
                ordering = '-{}'.format(ordering)
        return ordering

    def get_queryset(self):
        #form = PublicationForm(self.request.GET)
        authors = self.request.GET.getlist('author')
        translators = self.request.GET.getlist('translator')
        authors = Author.objects.filter(pk__in=authors).all()
        translators = Translator.objects.filter(pk__in=translators).all()
        form_of_publications = self.request.GET.getlist('form_of_publication')
        form_of_publications = FormOfPublication.objects.filter(pk__in=form_of_publications).all()
        languages = self.request.GET.getlist('language')
        languages = Language.objects.filter(pk__in=languages).all()
        affiliated_churches = self.request.GET.getlist('affiliated_church')
        affiliated_churches = Church.objects.filter(pk__in=affiliated_churches).all()
        content_genres = self.request.GET.getlist('content_genre')
        content_genres = Genre.objects.filter(pk__in=content_genres).all()
        connected_to_special_occasions = self.request.GET.getlist('connected_to_special_occasion')
        connected_to_special_occasions = SpecialOccasion.objects.filter(pk__in=connected_to_special_occasions).all()
        currently_owned_by = self.request.GET.getlist('currently_owned_by')
        currently_owned_by = Owner.objects.filter(pk__in=currently_owned_by).all()
        copyrights = self.request.GET.get('copyrights')
        is_a_translation =  self.request.GET.get('is_a_translation')
        publications = Publication.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)
        uploadedfiles = self.request.GET.getlist('uploadedfiles')
        uploadedfiles = UploadedFile.objects.filter(pk__in=uploadedfiles).all()
        keywords = self.request.GET.getlist('keywords')
        keywords = Keyword.objects.filter(pk__in=keywords).all()
        translated_from = self.request.GET.getlist('translated_From')
        translated_from = Language.objects.filter(pk__in=translated_from).all()
        city = self.request.GET.getlist('publication_city')
        country = self.request.GET.getlist('publication_country')
        collection_country = self.request.GET.getlist('collection_country')

        if list(collection_country) != ['']:
            collection_country = Country.objects.filter(pk__in=city).all()

        if list(country) != ['']:
            country = Country.objects.filter(pk__in=city).all()

        print('....', city)
        if list(city) != ['']:
            city = City.objects.filter(pk__in=city).all()

        print(publications)

        exclude = ['csrfmiddlewaretoken','search']
        in_variables = [('author', authors), ('translator', translators), ('form_of_publication', form_of_publications), ('language',languages), ('affiliated_church', affiliated_churches) \
        , ('content_genre', content_genres), ('connected_to_special_occasion', connected_to_special_occasions), ('currently_owned_by', currently_owned_by),\
        ('uploadedfiles', uploadedfiles), ('publication_country', country), ('publication_city', city), ('collection_country', collection_country), ('keywords', keywords), ('translated_from',translated_from)]
        special_case = ['copyrights', 'page', 'is_a_translation']

        if ('q' in self.request.GET) and self.request.GET['q'].strip():
            query_string = self.request.GET['q']
            if query_string.lower() in countries_dict.keys():
                query_string = countries_dict[query_string.lower()]
            search_fields = ['title_original', 'title_subtitle_transcription', 'title_subtitle_European', 'title_translation', 'author__name', 'author__name_original_language', 'author__extra_info', \
                  'form_of_publication__name', 'editor', 'printed_by', 'published_by', 'publication_date', 'publication_country__name', 'publication_city__name', 'publishing_organisation', 'translator__name', 'translator__name_original_language', 'translator__extra_info', \
                  'language__name', 'language__direction', 'affiliated_church__name', 'extra_info', 'content_genre__name', 'connected_to_special_occasion__name', 'donor', 'content_description', 'description_of_illustration', \
                  'nr_of_pages', 'collection_date', 'collection_country__name', 'collection_venue_and_city', 'contact_telephone_number', 'contact_email', 'contact_website', \
                  'currently_owned_by__name', 'uploadedfiles__description', 'uploadedfiles__uploaded_at', 'general_comments', 'team_comments', 'other_comments', 'keywords__name', 'is_a_translation', 'ISBN_number', 'translated_from__name', 'translated_from__direction']
            arabic_query = translator.translate(query_string, dest='ar').text
            query_string = to_searchable(query_string)
            #arabic_query = to_searchable(arabic_query)
            entry_query = get_query(query_string, search_fields)

            arabic_query = get_query(arabic_query, search_fields)
            print('&&&&&&', query_string)
            #publications = publications.filter(entry_query)
            publications = publications.filter(Q(entry_query) | Q(arabic_query))
            print(publications)
            publications = publications.distinct()
            return publications

        for field_name in self.request.GET:
            get_value = self.request.GET.get(field_name)
            if get_value != "" and not field_name in exclude and not field_name in [i[0] for i in in_variables] and\
               not field_name in special_case:
                print('******', field_name)
                arabic_query = translator.translate(get_value, dest='ar').text
                get_value = to_searchable(get_value)
                get_value = get_query(get_value, [field_name])
                arabic_query = get_query(arabic_query, [field_name])
                print('444444444', get_value)
                publications = publications.filter(Q(get_value) | Q(arabic_query))
                print('55555555555', publications)
                #publications = publications.filter(Q(**{field_name+'__regex':get_value}) | Q(**{field_name+'__icontains':arabic_query}) )

        for field_name, list_object in in_variables:
            print('****', list_object)
            if list_object:
                print('------', field_name)
                if list(list_object) != ['']:

                    publications = publications.filter(**{field_name+'__in': list_object})

        if str(copyrights) != "unknown" and str(copyrights) != "None":
            val = False
            if str(copyrights) == "yes":
                val = True
            print('11111', str(copyrights))
            publications = publications.filter(copyrights=val)

        print('666666', publications)

        if str(is_a_translation) != "unknown" and str(is_a_translation) != "None":
            val = False
            if str(is_a_translation) == "yes":
                val = True
            print('11111', str(is_a_translation))
            publications = publications.filter(is_a_translation=val)

        publications = publications.distinct()

        return publications
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. Basically if you have a get_queryset method you need to call get_ordering from there. Also for pagination you need to have the sorting variables in context so that if you go to page 2 for example, the ordering is maintained. Below is the solution code:

```
        ordering = self.get_ordering()
    if ordering is not None and ordering != "":
        publications = publications.order_by(ordering)
    return publications

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        order_by = self.request.GET.get('order_by')
        if order_by is not None and order_by != "":
            context['order_by'] = order_by
            context['direction'] = self.request.GET.get('direction')
        else:
            context['order_by'] = ''
            context['direction'] = ''
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if q is not None and q != "":
            context['q'] = q
        else:
            context['q'] = ''
        return context
```

And the html code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-light">  
    <tr>  
        <th>Title original  <a href="?q={{ q }}&order_by=title_original&direction=asc" class="arrow up"></a> <a href="?q={{ q }}&order_by=title_original&direction=desc" class="arrow down"></a></th>
        <th>Title subtitle transcription<a href="?q={{ q }}&order_by=title_subtitle_transcription&direction=asc" class="arrow up"></a> <a href="?q={{ q }}&order_by=title_subtitle_transcription&direction=desc" class="arrow down"></a></th>
        <th>Title translation<a href="?q={{ q }}&order_by=title_translation&direction=asc" class="arrow up"></a> <a href="?q={{ q }}&order_by=title_translation&direction=desc" class="arrow down"></a></th></th>
        <th>Actions</th>  
    </tr>  
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <br />
{% for publication in publications %}  
    <tr id="publications">
        <td style="text-align: start;unicode-bidi: plaintext;">{{ publication.title_original }}</td>
        <td>{{ publication.title_subtitle_transcription}}</td>
        <td>{{ publication.title_translation }}</td>  
        <td> 
            <a href="/publication/{{ publication.id }}/detail_view">View</a>
            <a href="/publication/{{ publication.id }}/edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" >Edit</span></a>  
            <a class="confirm-delete-pub" href="/publication/{{ publication.id }}/delete">Delete</a>
        </td>  
    </tr>  
{% endfor %}  
    </tbody>  
</table>
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?q={{ q }}&page=1&order_by={{order_by}}&direction={{ direction }}">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?q={{ q }}&page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}&order_by={{order_by}}&direction={{ direction }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?q={{ q }}&page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&order_by={{order_by}}&direction={{ direction }}">next</a>
            <a href="?q={{ q }}&page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}&order_by={{order_by}}&direction={{ direction }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_ordering` method

```
def get_ordering(self):
        ordering = self.request.GET.get('ordering', ''#default order param)
        return ordering
```

Comment: I have put my code in the get_ordering(self) . However it still runs the get_queryset(self) method. Do I need to add something to urls.py? I need ascending and descending. I still call them order_by and direction.

Comment: You must remove ordering codes from get_queryset. Also you can  manage direction with  `-` parameter. I mean that, you can send ordering parameter with `-` on url.

Comment: I have no ordering codes in get_queryset. I use the minus just like in the code above, should be sufficient? I have not used 'ordering' but 'order_by' and 'direction' just like above. This should not matter?'

Comment: It is not required. You can design as you can. Only, you must change parameter name. The important thing is: you must return a valid field name from this `get_ordering` method.

Comment: I still get this: FieldError at /
Cannot resolve keyword 'order_by' into field. And refers to get_queryset()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214250/discussion-between-emmanuel-chamilakis-and-kamilyrb).